# What is the best way to write it? Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, ejs

this is my first post : )
Someone can help me to improve my code to get a better way to write it?

```js
Temporada.findAll({
  where: { status: 1 }
}).then(temporadas => {


  Temporada.count({
    where: { status: 1 }
  }).then(temporadasAbertas => {
    if (temporadasAbertas > 0) {
      if (user_logged_acesso == 1) {
        JogoContagem.findAll({
          where: {
            j1Id: user_logged_id,
            status: { [Op.ne]: 0 }
          }
        }).then((blockeds) => {
          console.log(blockeds)
          res.render("painel/jogos/new", { users, user_logged_id, temporadas, blockeds });
        })
        
      } else {
        req.flash("error_msg", "No momento você não tem premissão de cadastrar jogos.");
        res.redirect("/painel");
      }
      
    } else {
      req.flash("error_msg", "No momento não há temporadas em aberto para cadastar jogos.");
      res.redirect("/painel");
    }
  })
  
})
```

It's working well, however I know that exist a better way to write it, maybe using functions with async await, but I don't know how to collect the results and insert the results to `res.render`. I guess I need to create a var with array... Anyway I suppose it... If you know a way let me know to I improve it.

Observation: My code have a few parts written in English and Portuguese, just if someone read and be curious to know which language. ( \o/ Hello from BRASIL )

thanks a lot,

Kind regards Davi Soares

Comment: If this code is working and you are soliciting improvements, the https://codereview.stackexchange.com is a good place to post.  Please read and follow the posting rules as it is more structured than here for exactly how you post.

Comment: Ok, I will use ir on my next posts, thanks for information.

Comment: Hi, it's best to give a meaningful title. "It" is not a keyword that anyone would search for in the future. IMO, titles should be chosen with future "searchers" in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you could do that with `await`. Inside an `async` function, do:

```
const temporadas = await Temporada.findAll({
  where: { status: 1 }
});
const temporadasAbertas = await Temporada.count({
  where: { status: 1 }
});
if (temporadasAbertas <= 0) {
  req.flash("error_msg", "No momento não há temporadas em aberto para cadastar jogos.");
  res.redirect("/painel");
  return;
}
if (user_logged_acesso !== 1) {
  req.flash("error_msg", "No momento você não tem premissão de cadastrar jogos.");
  res.redirect("/painel");
  return;
}
const blockeds = await JogoContagem.findAll({
  where: {
    j1Id: user_logged_id,
    status: {
      [Op.ne]: 0
    }
  }
});

res.render("painel/jogos/new", { users, user_logged_id, temporadas, blockeds });
```

Make sure to `.catch` errors too, either in a `catch` of a `try`/`catch`, or in a `.catch` onto the function call.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code:

```
router.get("/painel/jogos/new", authenticator, (req, res) => {
        var json = req.session.user;
        var user_logged = JSON.stringify(json);
        var user_logged = JSON.parse(user_logged);
        var user_logged_id = user_logged.id;
        var user_logged_acesso = user_logged.acesso;

        async function load() {
                try {
                        const loadUsers = await User.findAll({ where: { acesso: 1 }, order: [ ['primeiro_nome' , 'ASC'] ] })
                        const loadTemporadas = await Temporada.findAll({ where: { status: 1 } })
                        if (loadTemporadas[0] == null) { req.flash("error_msg", "No momento não há temporadas em aberto para cadastar jogos."); res.redirect("/painel"); }
                        const loadBlockeds = await JogoContagem.findAll({ where: { j1Id: user_logged_id, status: { [Op.ne]: 0 } } })

                        res.render("painel/jogos/new", { users: loadUsers, user_logged_id, temporadas: loadTemporadas, blockeds: loadBlockeds });
                } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                        req.flash("error_msg", "Ocorreu algum erro ao carregar a página, favor informar o administrador do site. ERROR CODE: /painel/jogos/new - LOAD"); 
                        res.redirect("/painel");
                }
        }
        load()
})
```